# LUIS dashboard analysis seems not be accurate to actual results especially for the unclear designation

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

Generally, when the dashboard informs you that there is an incorrect prediction the information is useful and can provided an actionable result.  However, for unclear time and time again I find issues with the analysis.

Moreover, things will be unclear and by the threshold that is used to give the unclear designation I find that in reality the intent doesn't really have that close of an unclear delta.

Example utterance:

Are there games tomorrow = intent: gamesInfoTime

Dashboard analysis = unclear prediction intent: gamesInfo at 0.0 spacing each equalling 100% prediction and thus an unclear intent.

Actual analysis = intent: gamesInfoTime = `"score": 0.999800742`
intent: gamesInfo = `"score": 0.8974294`

That is not as unclear and less cause for concern.  Why is the dashboard out of sync of the actual analysis.

I notice this and what is seemingly a delay to the unclear analysis.

Comment: does this happen for other apps as well or just for a specific app?

Comment: When you say other apps it mainly happens for this large model.